Clip NetCDF data by point shapefile in Python
I have .nc files containing global chl-a data. I want to clip these files using a point shapefile and get the chl-a values specifically for those points. However, every similar code that I have come across clips the data based on polygons. Is there any method available to get the point data instead?
